# jquery datePicker получить дату и не выводить в инпут

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

как получить значение datePicker, перехватить его, сделать изменения, какие то и потом самому поместить в инпут.
это мой код, так он вставляет в компонент дату, а мне нужно чтоб дата помещалась в переменну только.

```
$( e.target).datepicker({
                onSelect: date => {
                    console.log(date);
                }
            }).focus();
```

Comment: А какие изменения хотите сделать с датой?

Comment: поместить в переменную и не выводить в input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: date => {
      console.log(date);
      $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', null);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```